# Bit shifting in C

Tags: c

How would I do the following:

```
unsigned short x = 0xFFFF;
unsigned short y = 0xAE;

x |= y & 1;
x |= y & (1 << 1);
x |= y & (1 << 2);
x |= y & (1 << 3);
x |= y & (1 << 4);
x |= y & (1 << 5);
x |= y & (1 << 6);
x |= y & (1 << 7);
x |= y & (1 << 8);
x |= y & (1 << 9);
x |= y & (1 << 10);
x |= y & (1 << 11);
x |= y & (1 << 12);
x |= y & (1 << 13);
x |= y & (1 << 14);
x |= y & (1 << 15);
printf("%x", x);
```

I want x to be equal to 0xAE, but it is still equal to 0xFFFF.

Comment: Well, if you already know what you want x to equal, may I suggest `x = 0xAE`?

Comment: Unclear. "x = y" would do what you say. Do you want to set the lower 8 bits of x to equal the lower 8 bits of y, perhaps?

Comment: So there is no way to change a bit that is already 1 to a 0?

Comment: Yes, you can AND it with a mask which has every bit set, apart from the one which you wish to change to zero. e.g. x &= 0xFFFE will reset the rightmost bit to zero, leaving the others intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All bits are set already in x - so any `|=` operation on it won't change that.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to address each bit separately. The entire method can simply be reduced to

```
x &= y;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to start with

```
unsigned short x = 0x0000;
```

Answer (score 0):

C is calculating the correct thing, since what you're doing here is taking y, ANDING it with each bit from 0 to 15 which does produce AE. However, then you're doing OxFF | oxAE which is oxFF. Try setting the assigment operator to `&=`. That will do 0xFF & 0xAE which is 0xAE.